# elements don't shine through overlay

Tags: html, css, overlay

I want to create an overlay, which is shown, when an edit button is clicked. Only the edit fields should be visible through the overlay.
I have this div at the end of my html:

```
<div class='overlay closed'></div>
```

with following css:

```
.closed 
{
    display: none;
}
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 70;
}
```

This correctly shows an overlay over the website.

I have several forms, which should be accesible while the overlay is visible.
For example:

```
<div class='edit-container closed'>
   <form action="#" method='post'>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <input type='submit' value="safe" />
      <input type='reset' value='cancel' />
   </form>
</div>
```

i have tried following css to put those divs over the overlay:

```
#content.project .edit-container {
   z-index: 71;
}
#content.project .edit-container * {
    z-index: 71;   
}
```

Can you tell me why, or what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `position:relative;` on `edit-container`

http://jsfiddle.net/hwh0nnxo/

**HTML**

```
<div class='edit-container'>
   <form action="#" method='post'>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <input type='submit' value="safe" />
      <input type='reset' value='cancel' />
   </form>
</div>
<div class='overlay'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.closed {
    display: none;
}
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 70;
}
.edit-container{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 71;
}
```